# How to import CSV to SQL Server 2005 w/o BCP?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, csv, bulkinsert

I am working on a ColdFusion (feel free to laugh) 8 site that that is hosted in a shared environment. The database and the web server are separate boxes. We don't have root access to either, and we don't have "exec xp_cmdshell" permission. SQL Server version is 2005.

So, what is the closest equivalent to BULK INSERT that we should try if we would like to efficiently import a CSV or other text file into the database--but without BCP or "format files"?

Obviously, we could just build a massive INSERT statement in ColdFusion, with UNION ALLs for each row, and run that. But is that the best option? Your thoughts?

Comment: MERGE from a temp is "fastest" once the data is on the server (not sure if since 2005?). Using TDS is the "fastest" way to xfer the data, but likely not in CF8 (see SqlBulkCopy .NET class). As long as transactions are used correctly, many inserts statements are "ok". Not sure how it would compare with UNION ALL for a derived data-souce .. also can just use the "multi record" insert syntax to avoid union alls (barring the need to split up for maximum command sizes).

Comment: Okay, thanks for the response. Looks like we'll just be building a big-a$$ INSERT statement after all. :(  That's okay. We can wrap it in a transaction.

Comment: Can you not use SSIS? Wrapping in a transaction will degrade performance even further, although may be required for guaranteed consistency

Comment: I've actually never used SSIS/Business Intelligence Development Studio. I'll have to install that and see if our shared environment will allow it. Thanks. :)

Comment: I think I might try XML here...

Comment: @PeteCarter Wrapping it in a transaction will most likely *not* degrade performance further; without an explicit transaction, each statement will effectively run in it's own transaction .. it is the `sync` that is often expensive. Now, transaction interactions - especially over long operations - can get fun, but that's not performance per-say.

Comment: @pst wrapping the whole thing in a transaction will mean that you will not be able to achieve minimal logging, meaning extra IO and less performance, so I stand firmly behind the statement

Comment: What is "minimal logging"? How is there extra IO here? All I know is I can *insert* at upwards of 10,000 entries/second but I can only *commit* about 150/second (I use SSDs, so this is an easily valid value) - these numbers are an entire fabrication, but are *easily within the bounds of actual figures I have observed*. The ultimate issue is that a *commit* (implicit or explicit) requires a `sync` to ensure Durability. Other IO might never have to move out of buffers.

Comment: It is possible to get ColdFusion to read a CSV and and perform all the inserts. Hundreds of rows can be done very fast. Thousands if you want to run a background task. It may not be an ideal solution, but it will work

Comment: If you are looking for minimal logging, all of your options are explained at this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd425070(v=SQL.100).aspx  SQL 2005 is covered as well.